# How is it possible to perform a c-not on 4 qubits using the same control qubits on IBM Q computers?

Tags: quantum-gate, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I was wondering after seeing ibmq_16_melbourne layout how it is possible to perform this circuit :

[image]

It seems when looking at ibm q computers that a qubits can at max target 3 qubits because the arrow representing connectivity between qubits (which mean the possible cnots) doesn't allow more.

[image]

So how does the compiler map virtual qubits to physical quits in this case?

Comment: It would most likely include SWAP gates and adding in some H Gates to accomodate. An easy way to view it would be to build this circuit in qiskit and then call `transpile(circuit, backend)` where backend would be ibmq_16_melbourne in this case. Once you transpile it you can print/draw that circuit and see exactly what changes were made to make the circuit valid to run on melbourne

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use some trickery.

SWAP gates are the conceptually easiest method. For example, let's use qubit 5 as $a_0$, and then 5, 6 and 9 as $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$. Finally, let's use qubit 3 as $a_4$.

In this case, the only difficult cnot is `cx(5,3)`, between $a_0$ and $a_4$, which cannot be implemented directly. So we could apply a SWAP gate between qubits 3 and 4, which swaps their states. Implementing `cx(4,3)`, which is allowed by the device, then has much the same effect as `cx(5,3)` would have. To complete the effect, a final SWAP is applied.

Since a SWAP is implemented using three cnot gates, the above process requires 7 cnots to reproduce the effect of just one. It would therefore be good to find a more efficient option.

One possibility is the following

```
qc.cx(4,3)
qc.cx(5,4)
qc.cx(4,3)
qc.cx(5,4)
```

The end effect of this is to perform `qc.cx(5,3)`. It does this by making use of qubit 4. However, it does not matter what the state of qubit 4 was before the process is applied, and it leaves qubit 4 completely unchanged at the end.

A further option could be to encode the state of $a_0$ in many of the physical qubits on the device. For example, you could associate the $|0\rangle$/$|1\rangle$ state of $a_0$ with the $|000000\rangle$/$|111111\rangle$ states of qubits 1-6. Then a desired state $a |0\rangle+b|1\rangle$ would be encoded as $a |000000\rangle+b|111111\rangle$. A cnot can then be applied between this logical qubit and any of the 8 qubits it is connected to (0 and 7-13).